# firebaseAuth, how to check if user is signed in

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularjs-routing, firebasesimplelogin

Route:

```
var app = angular
  .module('defexApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'firebase'
  ])
  .constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://defex.firebaseio.com/')
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/landing.html',
      })
      .when('/add', {
        templateUrl: 'views/defects.html',
        controller: 'DefectCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        resolve: {
          currentUser: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.signedIn();
          }
        }
      })
      .when('/register',{
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        resolve: {
          currentUser: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.signedIn();
          }
        }
      })
      .when('/defects/:defectId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/defectview.html',
        controller: 'DefectViewCtrl',
        resolve: {
          currentUser: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.resolveUser();
          }
        }
      })
      .when('/defectlist', {
        templateUrl: 'views/defectList.html',
        controller: 'DefectCtrl',
        resolve: {
          currentUser: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.resolveUser();
          }
        }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Service:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Auth', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {

 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
 var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

 var Auth = {
    register: function(user) {
        return auth.$createUser({email: user.email, password: user.password});
    },
    login: function(user) {
        return auth.$authWithPassword({email: user.email, password: user.password});
    },
    logout: function() {
        return auth.$unauth();
    },
    resolveUser: function() {
        return auth.$requireAuth();
    },
    signedIn: function() {
        return auth.$waitForAuth();
    },

    user: {}

 };

return Auth;

});
```

I don't know if I am using $waitForAuth or $requireAuth correctly.  All I want to do is for the views /defects/:defectid and /defectlist, I want to make sure the user is authenticated before loading the view.  So I used the function which uses $requireAuth.  However, regardless if I am signed in or not, I am able to type in /defectlist in the address bar and have the view load which I am sure is not right.  Also, how do I check if a user is signed in?  I want to ng-hide or ng-show based on if a user is signed in or not and thought I could use $getAuth?  I am not sure.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed)? It utilizes the methods you've described here and demonstrates waiting for authentication, as well as redirects and other auth-related features. There is also a [section in the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication) dedicated to these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

showing/hiding elements and re-routing users depending on login state -- use the code from the docs to populate a user object that you store in your service. You can either have a resolve method in your routing config that checks to see if user object is null, or in your controller, when it loads, check to see if user object is null -- if it is null, re-route. If you don't want to re-route but just want to show/hide elements, use ng-show="user" or ng-hide="user"

```
// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
  //store the authData object in your service
  } else {
   //clear the authData object in your service
   //re-route user to logged out page
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
}
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how they want you to check for currently signed in users now:

`FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`

see [this example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/SignInActivity.java)